# User permissions on admin area

Tags: 6, users

I created a new role, and this role should only have the permissions to insert/edit/remove to content types.

The problem is that the admin menu ( Navigation Menu ) doesn't show up in the admin area, and I can't seem to figure out why.

The other problem is that if I login with this user, and access the create node by putting admin/node/add ( since the Navigation menu doesn't show up ), I can create every content type available.

What am I doing wrong?